# Get total number of lines before AWK's END

Tags: json, awk, git-log

I'm ALMOST managing to get a whole `git log` outputted to a valid `JSON` format, the only thing missing now is to get rid of a trailing comma at the end of the `JSON` array *(see output below)*.

Since I've used `awk`so far to get this working, I'd prefer to continue using it, unless I can get exactly the same output using something else. I am open to any suggestion!

The script is placed at the root of a `git` repository and run fron Terminal like:

```
./gitlog.sh
```

(considering you have already cd'ed to the root of the repository)

#### The script:

```
git log --all --no-merges --shortstat --pretty=format:'commit_hash %H commit_hash_abbreviated %h tree_hash %T tree_hash_abbreviated %t parent_hashes %P parent_hashes_abbreviated %p author_email %ae author_date %ad author_date_unix_timestamp %at author_date_iso_8601 %ai committer_email %ce' | paste -d " " - - - | tail -r | awk -v q='"' -v c=':' -v cl='{' -v cr='}' -v bl='[' -v br=']' -v e=',' -v t='    ' '
BEGIN {
    print cl;
    print t q "commits" q c bl;
}
{
    count++;
    print t t cl;
    print t t t q "commit_nr" q c q count q e;
    print t t t q "commit_hash" q c q $2 q e;
    print t t t q "commit_hash_abbreviated" q c q $4 q e;
    print t t t q "tree_hash" q c q $6 q e;
    print t t t q "tree_hash_abbreviated" q c q $8 q e;
    if ( count == 1 ) {
        print t t t q "parent_hashes" q c q "" q e;
        print t t t q "parent_hashes_abbreviated" q c q "" q e;
        print t t t q "author_email" q c q $12 q e;
        print t t t q "date_day_week" q c q $14 q e;
        print t t t q "date_month_name" q c q $15 q e;
        print t t t q "date_month_day" q c q $16 q e;
        print t t t q "date_hour" q c q $17 q e;
        print t t t q "date_year" q c q $18 q e;
        print t t t q "date_hour_gmt" q c q $19 q e;
        print t t t q "author_date_unix_timestamp" q c q $21 q e;
        print t t t q "date_iso_8601" q c q $23 q e;
        print t t t q "committer_email" q c q $27 q e;
        print t t t q "files_changed" q c q $28 q e;
        print t t t q "insertions" q c q $31 q e;
        print t t t q "deletions" q c q $33 q e;
        print t t t q "impact" q c q $31 - $33 q;
    } else {
        print t t t q "parent_hashes" q c q $10 q e;
        print t t t q "parent_hashes_abbreviated" q c q $12 q e;
        print t t t q "author_email" q c q $14 q e;
        print t t t q "date_day_week" q c q $16 q e;
        print t t t q "date_month_name" q c q $17 q e;
        print t t t q "date_month_day" q c q $18 q e;
        print t t t q "date_hour" q c q $19 q e;
        print t t t q "date_year" q c q $20 q e;
        print t t t q "date_hour_gmt" q c q $21 q e;
        print t t t q "author_date_unix_timestamp" q c q $23 q e;
        print t t t q "date_iso_8601" q c q $25 q e;
        print t t t q "committer_email" q c q $29 q e;
        print t t t q "files_changed" q c q $30 q e;
        print t t t q "insertions" q c q $33 q e;
        print t t t q "deletions" q c q $35 q e;
        print t t t q "impact" q c q $33 - $35 q;
    }
    print t t cr e;
} END {
    print t br;
    print cr;
}' > gitlog.json
```

#### The output:

*Shortened for the sake of example*

```
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "commit_nr":"1",
              "commit_hash":"c7a397928f814f29028bccb281de60066395eaa1",
              "commit_hash_abbreviated":"c7a3979",
              "tree_hash":"e38dac0e625f63e877baa329204511ae490cd944",
              "tree_hash_abbreviated":"e38dac0",
              "parent_hashes":"",
              "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"",
              "author_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "date_day_week":"Wed",
              "date_month_name":"Mar",
              "date_month_day":"6",
              "date_hour":"09:54:27",
              "date_year":"2013",
              "date_hour_gmt":"-0800",
              "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1362592467",
              "date_iso_8601":"2013-03-06",
              "committer_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "files_changed":"1",
              "insertions":"4",
              "deletions":"",
              "impact":"4"
          },
          {
              "commit_nr":"2",
              "commit_hash":"ee3810c9ff8fe144c9ee58f48d99f59885f03462",
              "commit_hash_abbreviated":"ee3810c",
              "tree_hash":"c6d102d3311a32a2475ba1539247f7ecc26b23d1",
              "tree_hash_abbreviated":"c6d102d",
              "parent_hashes":"c7a397928f814f29028bccb281de60066395eaa1",
              "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"c7a3979",
              "author_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "date_day_week":"Thu",
              "date_month_name":"Mar",
              "date_month_day":"7",
              "date_hour":"20:20:42",
              "date_year":"2013",
              "date_hour_gmt":"+0100",
              "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1362684042",
              "date_iso_8601":"2013-03-07",
              "committer_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "files_changed":"2",
              "insertions":"481133",
              "deletions":"",
              "impact":"481133"
          },
          {
              "commit_nr":"3",
              "commit_hash":"bc9a179663f00f134041ac750a56df8280e0b50b",
              "commit_hash_abbreviated":"bc9a179",
              "tree_hash":"f80d83c9e8e14ff55b2d77921cb0479bd173bae9",
              "tree_hash_abbreviated":"f80d83c",
              "parent_hashes":"ee3810c9ff8fe144c9ee58f48d99f59885f03462",
              "parent_hashes_abbreviated":"ee3810c",
              "author_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "date_day_week":"Thu",
              "date_month_name":"Mar",
              "date_month_day":"7",
              "date_hour":"20:22:03",
              "date_year":"2013",
              "date_hour_gmt":"+0100",
              "author_date_unix_timestamp":"1362684123",
              "date_iso_8601":"2013-03-07",
              "committer_email":"i@dreamyguy.com",
              "files_changed":"1",
              "insertions":"71",
              "deletions":"3",
              "impact":"68"
          },
      ]
  }
```

As you can see the problem here is that the line `print t t cr e;` outputs a comma (through the pre-defined `awk` variable I named `e`) for each line in the loop, including the last. :(

#### What I gave tried:

I replaced `print t t cr e;` with:

```
if (getline == 0) { print t t cr; } else { print t t cr e; }
```

`getline` is supposed to return `0` when it reaches the last line, but it's not a reliable solution: it stops in the 13th line of my 25 line output (25 commits). I've also tested this approach with the official git repository (https://github.com/git/git/commits/master). I still get the trailing comma after the last commit.

It might be `getline` is not getting the true number of lines because of some flaw in the script. But both `NR` and `count` return the accurate number of lines.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution you can try is adding the comma at the beginning of next line instead at the end of the previous one, and use the `printf` function to handle newlines.

Inside the `awk` script I check if line is not the first one and add a comma:

```
BEGIN {
    print cl;
    print t q "commits" q c bl;
}
{
    count++;
    #--------------------
    if ( count > 1 ) {
      printf "%s\n", e
    }
    #--------------------
    ...
} END {
    ...
}' > gitlog.json
```

And in the prints of last lines I use `printf` to avoid or add extra newlines:

```
...
printf "%s%s%s", t, t, cr;
} END {
    printf "\n%s%s\n", t, br;
    print cr;
}' > gitlog.json
```

I've tested it and seems to work. I hope it can be useful for you.

Comment: I got really stuck on this one... Your suggestion worked like a charm! I pushed a commit to my project at https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json/commit/51534bbea0fda32f9bce44348d6c0e528c3a6daf Cheers!